# Self Connection in Cluster Formation

Tags: c#, cluster-computing

I am currently working on cluster implementation, my question is during cluster formation when one node is started is it fine to create connection with itself, because when broadcasting a message the one who is broadcasting is also part of cluster and must recieve that broadcast message.....